# Binary Search Tree does not recognize values properly

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a Binary Serach Tree using C. Here in this code I added few values to the tree and then trying to check whether that values is in the tree. But my attempted code always return true.

I have checked many times. I am still learning C programming.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct BSTnode {
    int data;
    struct BSTnode *left;
    struct BSTnode *right;
    } BSTnode;

BSTnode *getNewNode(int data){
    BSTnode *newNode = (BSTnode*)malloc(sizeof(BSTnode));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->left=newNode->right=NULL;
    }
BSTnode* InsertNew(BSTnode *root,int data){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = getNewNode(data);
                }
        else if(data <= root->data){
            root->left = InsertNew(root->left,data);
            } else{
                root->right = InsertNew(root->right,data);
                }
        return root;
        }

bool search(BSTnode *root, int data){
    if(root== NULL) return false;
    else if(root->data == data) return true;
    else if (data <= root->data) return search(root->left,data);
    else return search(root->right,data);

    }
int main()
{
//node to store root

BSTnode *root = NULL;

root = InsertNew(root,34);
root = InsertNew(root,4);
root = InsertNew(root,3);
root = InsertNew(root,1);

int num;
printf("enter a number : \n");
num =scanf("%d");

if(search(root,num)==true){
    printf("found");
    }else{
    printf("not found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you haven't yet, then this is the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* and how to use it (and other techniques) to *debug* your program. I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: And also compile with warnings on. For example, you don't return anything from `getNewNode`, when you should return the new node.

Comment: Try to work on fixing the indentation of your code - this will help both you and the future reader of your code.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing that

```
num =scanf("%d");
```

doesn't do what you think it does (scanf returns the number of items successfully converted or -1 on `EOF`). You didn't crank your compiler's warning level high enough to tell you that you need

```
if (scanf ("%d", &num) != 1) {
    /* complain */
}
```

In your broken program, scanf() happens to return 1 (because it converted 1 item and wrote it to random memory) and since there's a 1 in the tree, you always get true.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the error pointed out by @Jens you are not returning a value from `getNewNode`. Add a statement:

```
return newNode;
```

at the end of that function. Here is a [fixed example on ideone](https://ideone.com/mffptR)

Comment: Please add `scanf("%d",&num);` to your answer. Because it was also a problem after fixing `return newNode;`

Comment: I have started my answer with `In addition to the error pointed out by @Jens` and I realize this is a problem, but that error was not spotted by me. Jens' answer gives enough detail on that and I don't see value in duplicating his explanation in my answer

Answer (score 3):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `getNewNode`

```
BSTnode *getNewNode(int data){
    BSTnode *newNode = (BSTnode*)malloc(sizeof(BSTnode));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->left=newNode->right=NULL;
    }
```

has undefined behavior because it returns nothing though has the return type `BSTnode *`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
BSTnode * getNewNode( int data )
{
    BSTnode *newNode = ( BSTnode * )malloc( sizeof( BSTnode ) );

    if ( newNode != NULL )
    {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

The function `InsertNew` is wrong.Take into account that for binary search tree there is usually used the operator `<` instead of the operator `<=`.

These statements

```
root->left = InsertNew(root->left,data);
```

and

```
root->right = InsertNew(root->right,data);
```

do not make sense and overwrites the values of `root->left` and `root->right`  of nodes that shall not be actually changed. Also  the created node can be equal to NULL and in this case the original root node will be also overwritten by NULL.

It is better to pass the original root node by reference through pointer.

Also you should use `operator <` instead of the `operator <=`.

The function definition can look the following way

```
BSTnode * InsertNew( BSTnode **root,int data )
{
    if ( *root == NULL )
    {
        *root = getNewNode( data );
        return *root;
    }
    else if ( data < ( *root )->data )
    {
        return InsertNew( &( *root->left ), data );
    } 
    else
    {
        return InsertNew( &( *root->right ), data );
    }
}
```

and the function can be called like

```
InsertNew( &root, 34 );
```

without assigning the return pointer to the root node. The return value can be checked in an if statement if it is needed.

If you do not want to have duplicate values in the tree then the function can be written the following way

```
BSTnode * InsertNew( BSTnode **root,int data )
{
    if ( *root == NULL )
    {
        *root = getNewNode( data );
        return *root;
    }
    else if ( data < ( *root )->data )
    {
        return InsertNew( &( *root->left ), data );
    } 
    else if ( ( *root )->data < data )
    {
        return InsertNew( &( *root->right ), data );
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Correspondingly the function `search` should be defined like

```
bool search( BSTnode *root, int data )
{
    if ( root == NULL ) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( data < root->data ) 
    {
        return search( root->left, data );
    }
    else if ( root->data < data )
    {
        return search( root->right, data );
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The using of the function `scanf` in this statement

```
num =scanf("%d");
```

is wrong.

The correct call will look like

```
printf( "enter a number : " );
scanf( "%d", &num );
```

You can also check whether the call was successful by using the condition in an if statement

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &num ) == 1 )
{
    //...
}
```

And you should free all allocated memory for the tree before exiting the program.

In general it is better to use the following condition

```
if(search(root,num) ){
```

instead of the strict comparison with true

```
if(search(root,num)==true){
```

because if the function will be rewritten such a way that in the case of success it will return any non-zero value then the strict comparison with `true` will not work.